# How to query by joining 2 documents based on the _id in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have a data model like this picture below and all of them are in the same collection, but of course are different in data structure. I used the manual references in document movies and document studios. For example, like the code below:

- For document people

  {
  "_id": 100600,
  "first_name": "Becka",
  "last_name": "Battson",
  "birth_day": "2001-10-03"
  }
- For document movies

  {
  "_id": 1100,
  "title": "Tom and Jerry",
  "director_id": 100100,
  "release_year": 2018,
  "imdb": {
  "rating": 4.8,
  "votes": 100
  },
  "actors": [
  {
  "person_id": 100300,
  "as": "Tom"
  },
  {
  "person_id": 100400,
  "as": "Jerry"
  },
  {
  "person_id": 100500,
  "as": "Nibbles"
  }
  ]
  }
- For document studios:

  {
  "_id": 9991000,
  "name": "Walt Disney",
  "year_founded": 1923,
  "movies": [
  1100,
  1200
  ],
  "headquarters": {
  "address": "1375 E Buena Vista Dr",
  "city": "New York",
  "state": "New York",
  "country": "US"
  }
  }

I have some tasks that need join between 2 documents together to get data. For example, ***"Indicates that the movies have the actor has the last name "Battson"*** . But I know that MongoDB doesn't support join documents like joining 2 tables in RDBMS.

I have tried to used this code below in MongoDB shell but it doesn't make sense. I think I need to get the values from the _id in the result query, then push them into the array array_idActor so that the second code can run:

```
const array_idActor = db.getCollection('movies_subject').find({last_name: /Battson/})
db.getCollection('movies_subject').find({actors:{$elemMatch:{person_id:{$in:array_idActor}}}}).pretty()
```

Please help me to fix this. Thank you so much.

Comment: Here is the data model. You can see it in the image link: https://imgur.com/a/e1ICYOc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

join **two** collections

```
db.people.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "last_name": "Battson"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "movies",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "actors.person_id",
      "as": "movie_docs"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oYwyMsBfVZJ)

---

join **three** collections

```
db.people.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "last_name": "Battson"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "movies",
      "let": {
        "people_id": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$in": [
                "$$people_id",
                "$actors.person_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$lookup": {
            "from": "studios",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "movies",
            "as": "studio_docs"
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "movie_docs"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_dokRyHDvhX)

---

**same** collection

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "last_name": "Battson"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "actors.person_id",
      "as": "movie_docs"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LY0xU0LoTLJ)

Comment: Thank you so much, but all of them are in the same collection called "movie_subject", so can I use the aggregate and your query to apply for all documents which are in the same collection?

Comment: @OrangePumpkin Sure, I update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much, I've tried and it worked for me.

Comment: @OrangePumpkin Perfect! It would be great if you can accept this answer and give it a up vote.